# What is wrong with this Python program?

Tags: python

```
string = ''
l3 = []
l4 = []
l = []
obj = open('input.txt', 'r')
l1 = obj.readlines()

for i in l1:
    l2 = i.split()
    for j in l2:
        if j != '+' or j != '-' or j != '*' or j != '/':
            l3.append(j)
        else:
            l4.append(j)

    l3.reverse()
    l4.reverse()
    while len(l3) != 0 and len(l4) != 0:
        d = l3[len(l3) - 1]
        del l3[len(l3) - 1]
        e = l4[len(l4) - 1]
        del l4[len(l4) - 1]
        f = l3[len(l3) - 1]
        del l3[len(l3) - 1]
        string = string + '(' + d + e + f + ')'
    string += '\n'
    l.append(string)
j = open('output.txt', 'w')
j.writelines(l)
```

when i excecute the program and i open output.txt,I get a blank file!
Please note that I am a beginner and i know nothing more about python than what i have used!
Stacks:
I'm sorry here's the QUESTION:
STACKS:
Stack is a data structure (just like lists), in which data is added and removed only at one end,called the top

● To add (push) an item to the stack, it must be placed on the top of the stack.

● To remove (pop) an item from the stack, it must be removed only if it is at the top of
the stack too.

● Thus, the last element that is pushed into the stack, is the first element to be popped
out of the stack
Many examples of stacks occur in everyday situations. Almost any cafeteria has a stack of
trays or plates. You can remove and add a plate only at the top.

Infix expressions:

Operators are written in­ between their operands. This is the usual way we write
expressions. An expression such as A * ( B + C ) / D
                 is usually taken to mean

Postfix expressions:

Here, operators are written after their operands. The infix expression given above is
equivalent to A B C + * D / 
The order of evaluation of operators is always left­ to­ right, and brackets cannot be used to change this order. Because the "+" is to the left of the "*" in the example above, the addition must be performed before the multiplication.

Converting between these notations:

You can convert directly between these bracketed forms simply by moving the operator
within the brackets e.g. (X + Y) to (X Y +). Repeat this for all the operators in an
expression, and finally remove any superfluous brackets.

Problem Statement:
Write a program to read a postfix expression from an input file, evaluate the expression
and print the result to an output file. You may assume that the expression involves only
numbers and arthimetic operators, not variables as in the given examples.

Hint: Use a stack (Stacks can be implemented using Python lists)

Comment: it was really badly formatted for a starter, so I've reformatted it; please read http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/; also, the naming of variables is terrible; and it really looks like a bit like C code translated into Python.

Comment: Whoah, that's a bunch of ugly and unreadable code.

Comment: I've added the question.I'm sorry I did'nt do it before!

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what this program is attempting to do, but one thing that leaps to mind is that you forgot to close the file:

```
j.close()
```

should be called at the end.

Even better, use a `with` block to have Python close it automatically:

```
with open('output.txt','w') as j:
    j.writelines(l)
```

Some other tips:

Use better variable names. `j`, `l3` etc. are unhelpful to whoever reads your program (including you). `l3` is especially bad since it almost looks like `13`.

Instead of `if j!='+' or j!='-' or j!='*' or j!='/':` (which is always `True`, regardless of `j`'s value), you probably meant

```
if not j in ('+', '-', '*', '/'):
```

Comment: Those two conditions don't mean the same thing. The first means if `j` is not *one* of those: ie even if it's `+`, it's still not `-` so the condition is true. I expect that your revised condition is what OP actually means, though.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I think so, too, otherwise the condition would always be true.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using 'del' you could directly assign the last element, while deleting it from the list by:

```
d = l3.pop()
e = l4.pop()
f = l3.pop()
```